# Special character sets in ANTLR C++ target

Tags: antlr3

I am using ANTLR 3.5 version for parsing our grammer in c++.
The input file contains the extended characters like "°".ANTLR is not able to match these character with Lexer rule.
Can any one suggest how to match Extended characters in ANTLR

Answer (score 0):

What Unicode codepoint is that? Keep in mind ANTLR (including ANLTR 4) only can handle the Unicode BMP ([Basic Multilingual Plane](http://www.unicode.org/roadmaps/bmp/)). You cannot parse input the contains characters beyond that.